# Linux Kernel configuring swapping parameters.

Tags: linux, kernel, swap, swap-file, swappiness

> Linux may perform a swap out on the following occasions:
>
> - By a kernel thread denoted as `kswapd` that is activated periodically whenever the number of free page frames falls below a
>     predefined threshold.
> - When a memory request to the buddy system cannot be satisfied because the number of free page frames would fall below a predefined
>     threshold.

I read the above in a book. I did not find what is parameter for determining the interval of the `kswapd`. Is there a way to configure the swapping parameters when kernel starts?

Comment: Look up vm.swappiness addition to your init files.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Found an interesting discussion at https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness but nothing on the kswapd scheduling.